# Workflow WCF Service - Can't call from application - The request object expects an argument that I can't identify

Tags: wcf, workflow

I have created a WCF service using Workflow. It works just fine. I created another Workflow application to consume it. I added the service reference to the application project and rebuilt the project. I added the component from the service to the app, but it's expecting an argument that I never specified.

I've tried rebuilding both the service and the app, generating an entirely new solution and starting from scratch - same problem. I've looked at others' code and they've structured this project the same as mine but this issue does not show up on theirs. Googling this problem seems to bring up not results.

My workflow service is defined as such: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQXkv.png

The parameters of the receive component are: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP1Pw.png

But when I add it to my app, the parameters are defined as: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eOoT.png

Which is not what I had defined in my service. I can't even figure out what it wants me to pass in for _GetCityStateFromZip. It says the type is InArgument.

I was expecting it to be expecting the zipcode parameter as I specified in the service. I think I might be adding the service reference incorrectly, but I don't know how. I went to Add Service Reference in Visual Studio, then copy/pasted the path to the .xamlx file of the service on localhost.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5279fc5f-8a53-43e7-8ef2-3073808dc90f/configuring-workflow-services-how-to-configure-workflow-control-endpoint?forum=wfprerelease

I re-made my service using the steps listed and it works as originally intended.